# Order of points on a line

Tags: geometry

Given a 3D vector defining a line and two points known to be on that line how would you calculate which is furthest along the line?

By furthest I mean, in the direction of the vector. I.E. furthest from the origin.

EG if I had a point in 2D space a[5, 0] and another b[12, 0] and a normalised vector defining the line [1, 0] how could I find out if a was behind b.

Comment: Given any two points $(x,y,z),(u,v,w)\in\Bbb R^3$, if $x^2+y^2+z^2>u^2+v^2+w^2$, then the point $(x,y,z)$ is farther from the origin. It doesn't mater if they are on the given line or not.  Look into [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).

Comment: I have been over thinking it for over 45 minutes. Thank you

Comment: No problem. I suggest you answer your own question so this question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was really over-thinking the problem. realistically speaking I just needed the distance. I.E.

```
(x,y,z)
(u,v,w)∈R3 

if x2+y2+z2 > u2+v2+w2.
```